# Woocommerce add classes to tags

Tags: wordpress, tags, woocommerce

I'd like to add class to tags in woocommerce product tags.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
    echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
?>
```

Output

```
<a rel="tag" href="">spicy</a>
```

What I want

```
<a rel="tag" href="" class="spicy" title="spicy">spicy</a>
```

Comment: In your code you're using a variable named `$tag_count`. Can you please show the piece of code where this variable is defined?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that: 
$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );

Here's the full code: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/meta.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );

$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    $html .= "<a href='/product-tag/{$tag->term_id}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a> ";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesnt work. I'd imagine this will work for regular wordpress post.

Comment: @Jenny this is a tested piece of code and it's confirmed to be working. Here is the output on a WC product: `<div class="post_tags"><a href='/product-tag/29' title='tag1 Tag' class='tag1'>tag1</a> <a href='/product-tag/30' title='tag2 Tag' class='tag2'>tag2</a> </div>`. If you're having issues with it, then there are additional problems with your code that we're not aware of.

Comment: I'm trying to put that code here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product.php

Any conflicts here? I'm getting error on the foreach loop.

Comment: If you don't show us the error you're getting, and the actual code that you're using, I'm afraid there is very little we can do to help. What I can only guess from your comment is that you did not modify the correct template file. You are showing me the `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`, but you should actually modify `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/meta.php`. Again, I am only guessing. This is the `meta.php` code: http://laravel.io/bin/nQ2Oq

Comment: I see. Yes it is working now. Thanks alot! 

Can you also help me with a if statement? If have product tag show that code?

Comment: I'm pretty busy currently, so I'm not sure when (or if) I'll be able to, but if I do, I'll leave another comment here. I'm sorry I really can't give you any promises.

Comment: No Worries, I have it all figured out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, i know what is the problem. When on page exist product without tags, foreach get a string in first arg. Just add if else instruction. And I corrected code for links.

```
    $tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );
    if ($tags === false){
    }
    else{
        $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
            $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
            $html .= "{$tag->name}</a> ";
        }
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;
    }
```